# Exporting Jabref data between computers

Tags: latex, export, bibtex, bibliography

I'll be moving from my Mac OS X 10.5.8 to Ubutnu 11.10 shortly.
I realized that I have about 150+ references along with files (in .pdf format) managed in Jabref.
Is there anyway to export my .bib file ALONG with all my .pdf files from my current OS X to Ubuntu 11.10?

Any user written scripts that anyone may suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually figured this out and it's not so bad! 
All you have to do is copy your pdfs/papers to your new computer/directory and change this attribute in your .bib file.